# Calcuate Bayes Factor for Adjusted Mean Difference

Tags: r, t-test, ancova, bayes

I have an ANCOVA model shown below (*fit*) where I calculated the mean difference between two groups while controlling for another variable (*x*).  For the adjusted mean difference (288.72), I'd like to calculate a Bayes Factor for two hypotheses: adj. mean difference = 0; adj. mean difference > 0.  I tried doing this by using the ttest.tstat() function provided by the BayesFactor library (see below) and got a Bayes Factor of 2.53.

Could you tell me if this is the correct way of calculating a Bayes Factor for an adjusted mean difference?  If not, what method should I follow?

Thanks in advance!

```
set.seed(1000)

library(BayesFactor)

data <- data.frame(group=factor(c(rep("Group 1", 100), rep("Group 2", 100))))
data$x <- rnorm(200, m=30, sd=20) + c(rep(0, 100), rep(1, 100))*25
data$y <- 500 + data$x*2.5 + c(rep(0, 100), rep(1, 100))*200 + 
          rnorm(200, m=0, sd=600)

fit <- lm(y~x+group, data=data)

summary(fit)

# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x + group, data = data)
#
# Residuals:
#      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -1617.78  -408.91   -62.18   454.00  1318.24 
#
# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  511.6963    88.8485   5.759 3.21e-08 ***
# x              0.9481     2.1912   0.433  0.66572    
# groupGroup 2 288.7235   101.8529   2.835  0.00506 ** 
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
#
# Residual standard error: 589.8 on 197 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared: 0.06795,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.05849 
# F-statistic: 7.181 on 2 and 197 DF,  p-value: 0.0009764 

ttest.tstat(t=2.835, n1=100, n2=100, nullInterval=c(0, Inf))

# $bf
#      null       alt 
#  2.531284 -3.207229 
#
# $properror
#         null          alt 
# 1.810593e-05 5.552613e-03
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like as of BayesFactor version 0.9.2, categorical and continuous can be included in the same model when using the lmBF() function.

Following the tutorial on the BayesFactors website (http://bayesfactorpcl.r-forge.r-project.org/#glm), I calculated a Bayes Factor for the adjusted mean difference like so:

```
base.fit <- lmBF(y~x, data=data)
full.fit <- lmBF(y~x+group, data=data)

full.fit / base.fit

# Bayes factor analysis
# --------------
# [1] x + group : 8.127295 ±2.08%
#
# Against denominator:
#   y ~ x 
# ---
# Bayes factor type: BFlinearModel, JZS
```